# Saving MAT Images in to a vector. (Memory and Speed Problems)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a little issue. Below I am scanning an image according to a user defined ROI. everything works fine however when I try to scan my image with the sliding size of one pixel, I get error in pushbacks. I wonder why? Are there any memory problems?

```
 vector<Mat> images;
vector < pair < int, int > > Coordinate;
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= lBPIIImage2.rows - roih; rowIndex = getNextIndex(rowIndex, lBPIIImage2.rows, roih, 1))

    {
        for (int colindex = 0; colindex <= lBPIIImage2.cols - roiw; colindex = getNextIndex(colindex, lBPIIImage2.cols, roiw, 1))

        {
            searchRect = cvRect(colindex, rowIndex, roiw, roih);
            frameSearchRect = lBPIIImage2(searchRect);
            LoopDummy = frameSearchRect.clone();
            rectangle(frame, searchRect, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);

            images.push_back(LoopDummy);
            Coordinate.push_back(make_pair(rowIndex, colindex));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which error? [mcve] please

Comment: In `images.push_back(LoopDummy);` line when the scan steps are very little number of scanned images are increasing. Thus I am not able to store them  into images vector. However when the step size is large (7 pixels or larger) I am able to  store the extracted windows. @Miki

Comment: Where are you sizing your vector?

Comment: Some implementations of the STL have an initial size for vector (some do not). Assuming you are using an STL vector and not some other implementation: vectors are contiguous containers that need to be sized (as opposed to non-contiguous containers that grow automatically). Contiguous containers are fast if you know the size in advance, but slow if you are constantly re-sizing them (which requires a copy). Non-contiguous containers are constant speed in single threaded mode, but slower than contiguous containers of fixed size.

Comment: @IanThompson I guess if I size my vector according to aspected window it would be better. Just some aritmetics.. TY

Comment: @Hertzial_97 Well, it might be _better_ but it would still be wrong. What would be ideal is if you make an initial guess, but before you push_back, check that you haven't exceeded the size of the vector and re-size it. You can use a simple doubling algorithm, which risks running out of memory, but is much faster, or you can experiment and find an exponent to scale by that minimises resizing. Alternatively, you could use a non-contiguous container and boost::pool